# Action bar, Navigation Drawer , Cards UI support from Android 2.2

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, backwards-compatibility, android-cards

i am developing a new application.My UI consists Cards , Action bar , Navigation Drawer. i have done this for Android 4.0 and above but now i  need to support from Android 2.2 devices. Is it possible to support these functionality from android 2.2. Is there any libraries available to support low end devices also ?

please help

Comment: For `ActionBar` you have `android.support.v7` which is a support library provided by android

Comment: https://github.com/nirmal66/SlidingMenu/blob/master/src/com/example/allslidingmenu/MainActivity.java use this library for supporting from android 2.2 change the theme..

Answer (score 1):

Go for android support v4, v6 or v7 libraries,

They have the support for following features

1.Navigation drawer
2.Action bars

and many more.

Please refer to the following link

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html